# How to loop through each image and set the size for each individual image?

Tags: jquery

My code below works fine for getting the size of the first image and then adding `margin-top` and `margin-left` to each image on the page. But it's using the first image as a basis for all the other images. How can I loop through and use the size of each image to find the values it should be using for margin-left and margin-top?

```
$j(document).ready(function () {

//get the image size:
var theHeight = $j("#co-logo img").height();
var theWidth = $j("#logo img").width();

//place them into the image styles:
$j("#co-logo img").css({ 'margin-top': -theHeight / 2 + "px", 'margin-left': -theWidth / 2 + "px" });

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `.each()`:

```
$j(document).ready(
    function(){

    $('#co-logo img').each(
        function(){
            var theWidth = $(this).width();
            var theHeight = $(this).height();

            $(this).css({'margin-top': -theHeight / 2 + 'px', 'margin-left': -theWidth / 2 + 'px'});
        });
    });
```

References:

- [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).